# getDate function OOP dilema

Tags: php, datetime

Times and times again I encounter this problem:

You have a object with date (datetime)  `$object->date` which is presented in **several formats**
in the front-end... and in some cases **can be empty**.

So my usual approach for this is in the model:

```
public function getDate(){
    if($this->date){
        return DateTime($this->date);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And use it in like `$object->getDate()->format('d-m-Y')`;
This is cool ... but as mentioned above, there may be some objects with empty date,
and the above call will result in "`...format() on a non object...`" Exception.

The work around for this is to always check for empty:
 `$object->getDate() ? $object->getDate()->format('d-m-Y') : "";`

And this is too long and ugly to use every time you need the date.

So my final solution is to consolidate the check within the method:

```
public function getDate($format = false, $empty_str = ""){
    if($format){
        if($this->date){
            $dt = new DateTime($this->date);
            return $dt->format($format);
        }
        return $empty_str;    
    }else{
        return new DateTime($this->date);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** reviewing my code after few years I come up with better formating:

```
public function getDate($format = false, $empty_str = ""){ 
    if (!$this->date) {
        return $empty_str;
    }

    $dt = new DateTime($this->date);
    return ($format) ? $dt->format($format) : $dt;
}
```

The usage is cool:

```
$object->getDate('d-m-Y');
$object->getDate('d-m-Y', 'no date');
$object->getDate(); // DateTime object
```

My only concern here is .. the method trashes several OOP principles and looks too custom.

Is there a better approach for this ? It is common problem so **it should have** good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a specific class like

```
class NullObject {

    public function __get($var) {
        return null;
    }

    public function __call($funcname, $params) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

and instead of simply returning `null` you do

```
return new NullObject();
```

Comment: this looks interesting, it is more universal  `NullObject`
instead of null for chainable calls... but there is something evil in it :)

Comment: Yes, you're right, that is even better! It depends on whether you use it only in this specific case and want minimum changes, or whether you're willing to change your practice and use `$var instanceof NullObject` instead of `$var === null` in conditions. Of course you should know where to not use it. Somewhere later it may break other things. But I'm pretty sure, you'll handle it.

Comment: Just a supplementary idea: to avoid changing to many return values you could write a small function `function silenceNull($returnvalue) { if($returnvalue === null) return new NullObject(); return $returnvalue; }` and use it like this: `silenceNull( $object->getDate() )->format('d-m-Y');`

Comment: @Robert: you don't even need to `return null;`, because default return is `null`.

Comment: @Glavić: yeah, you're right, thats even shorter! I'm just used to always return something ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getDate($format = "default format", $empty_str = ""){

    if($this->date){
        $dt = new DateTime($this->date);
        return $dt->format($format);
    }
    return $empty_str;  
}
```

Comment: you just trimmed the option to get DateTime object if no params are given... and there is rarely such thing as "default format"

Comment: Yeah but there is no way to do what you want - without any checks to skip calling a function of a non object :)